# Filter pyspark dataframe but still on dataframe format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

How to filter pyspark dataframe but still on dataframe format?

I used this

`datalabel = datalabel.filter(datalabel.subs_no.isNotNull()).collect()`

but `datalabel` format is change to list.

Comment: Your question is very vague

Comment: `datalabel.filter(datalabel.subs_no.isNotNull())` gives you a data frame back. When you call `.collect()` on it, you are requesting a list of rows. So just remove `.collect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the required columns using `select` which will return a `DataFrame`

```
datalabel_subs_no = datalabel.filter(datalabel.subs_no.isNotNull()).select(F.col('subs_no'))
```